# Assistance Required with PUT API Request to Update iSheet Column in HighQ

Tags: json, spreadsheet

I am currently working on integrating our system with HighQ by automating the process of updating iSheet columns via the HighQ API. My goal is to update the "attributecolumnid" 1691 with values extracted from a JSON file containing student information.

Here is a sample of the JSON structure I am working with:

```
{
  "HighQ ID": "HQ01",
  "Student Street Address": "3539 Kingsland Avenue",
  "Student City": "Bronx",
  "Student State": "",
  "Student Zip Code": "10469",
  "Student Home District": "14"
}
```

I intend to use the following PUT API request to update the "Student Home District" value into the iSheet:

PUT {{URI}}/api/18/isheet/3/items/1691

Below is the body of my PUT request:

```
{
  "type": "Http",
  "inputs": {
    "uri": "{{URI}}/api/18/isheet/3/items/1691",
    "method": "PUT",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer @{body('Get_secret')?['value']}"
    },
    "body": {
      "data": {
        "item": [
          {
            "column": [
              {
                "attributecolumnid": "1691",
                "string": {
                  "rawdata": "@{variables('School District Goat')}"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "Append_to_array_variable": [
      "SUCCEEDED"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeConfiguration": {
    "contentTransfer": {
      "transferMode": "Chunked"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, my attempts have been met with this response:

> "403 Validation failed | Forbidden"

This leads me to believe there might be an issue related to the structure of my request as I validated my permission with another PUT API that I was able to successfully run.

Could you provide guidance or an example of how to successfully use the PUT API for updating a single column in HighQ? Any insights into resolving the 403 error would also be greatly appreciated.